# search-query for calendar entries after a specific date with Powershell search-mailbox not working

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to search for Calendar entries that start in 2015 and i can't get any results.

```
Search-Mailbox  $mb -TargetMailbox $t_mb -TargetFolder result -LogOnly 

SearchQuery 'start:> 2015-01-01'
```

for the field name I have tried `startdate` and `start_date`
other date values i have used are 01/01/2015 and "today"

All return `0 results`, if i search on a particular subject i can get 100+ results.
Looking for insight on how to query for calendar dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your original query. Instead of using `-SearchQuery ...`, do `-StartDate "01/01/2015"`

Comment: -StartDate does not come up as an available parameter.  I tried it anyway but got the error: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'StartDate'.

Answer (score 0):

Found this page  (finally):
[Exchange keywords](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj983804%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

So the only valid date fields you can search on are Sent, Received and Lastattempttime. A query to find calendar entries with a start date of x, simply does not exist.